# Enum для каждого enum

Tags: java

Собственно, вопрос, как это выглядит?
Для примера возьмем:

```
   public enum Transport{
        SHOTGUN, RIFLE, MINIGUN
   }
```

И вот для каждого перечисления нужно задать еще один enum для конкретной модели.
Как это будет выглядеть и как к этому обращаться?
изначально мне кажется что должна присутствовать строка

```
    public Transport(Enum type){this.type = type};
```

Но ведь для каждого перечисления будет свое перечисление. И перечисление нельзя наследовать. Подскажите.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Определите интерфейс, который должны будут реализовывать ваши вложенные перечисления.

```
public enum Transport {
    SHOTGUN(Type1.T11),
    RIFLE(Type2.T21),
    MINIGUN(Type3.T31);

    private Weapon weapon;

    Transport(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public interface Weapon {};

    public enum Type1 implements Weapon {
        T11, T12;
    }

    public enum Type2 implements Weapon {
        T21, T22;
    }

    public enum Type3 implements Weapon {
        T31, T32;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

с наследованием наверняка не получится...

```
    public class EnumManager
    {
        public enum ABC
        {
            A, B, C
        }

        public enum DEF
        {
            D, E, F
        }

        public enum GHJ
        {
            G, H, J
        }

        public enum Transport
        {
            SHOTGUN, RIFLE, MINIGUN
        }

        private static final Map < Transport, Enum < ? >[] > children = new HashMap < Transport, Enum < ? >[] > () ;
        static
        {
            children.put ( Transport.SHOTGUN, ABC.values () ) ;
            children.put ( Transport.RIFLE, DEF.values () ) ;
            children.put ( Transport.MINIGUN, GHJ.values () ) ;
        }

        public static Enum < ? >[] getChildren ( final Transport parent )
        {
            return children.get ( parent ) ;
        }

        public static void main ( final String[] args )
        {
            for ( final Transport t : Transport.values () )
            {
                System.out.println ( Arrays.toString ( getChildren ( t ) ) ) ;
            }

        }
    }
```

выводит:

```
[A, B, C]
[D, E, F]
[G, H, J]
```